# How is filter implemented?

Tags: filter, scheme

Need help on this one using scheme function
Return a list containing all elements of a given list that satisfy a given predicate. For example, `(filter (lambda (x) (< x 5)) '(3 9 5 8 2 4 7))` should return `(3 2 4)`.

Comment: Please try to explain your problem more clearly. Are you trying to figure out how to implement the filter function?

Comment: Is this homework? Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: I'm forced to downvote the question until it explains what the problem is.  The question currently only has a description of the filter function.  I can not tell what the poster is having difficulty with yet.

Comment: It's an implentation detail that is subject to change and depends on your vendor ;D

Answer (score 6):

filterb - just in case there is already a function called filter.

```
(define filterb
    (lambda (pred lst)
      (cond ((null? lst) '())
            ((pred (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (filterb pred (cdr lst))))
            (else (filterb pred (cdr lst))))))
```

Here it is, though I am sure it can be made to look nicer.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to write the `filter` procedure:

```
(define (my-filter pred lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) null)
        ((pred (first lst))
         (cons (first lst) (my-filter pred (rest lst))))
        (else (my-filter pred (rest lst)))))
```

Notice that I named the procedure `my-filter`, because a built-in procedure called `filter` already exists and it's not a good idea to overwrite its definition.

Answer (score 1):

The textbook definition of filter is the (non-tail) recursive one that other posters have shown—and it's important to understand that one.  However, if you're writing it as a library function, it's useful to figure out how to do it with tail recursion, so that you don't blow up the stack or heap with long lists:

```
(define (filter pred? list)
  (define (filter-aux result current-pair xs)
    (cond ((null? xs)
           result)
          ((pred? (car xs))
           (set-cdr! current-pair
                     (cons (car xs)
                           '()))
           (filter-aux result
                       (cdr current-pair)
                       (cdr xs)))
          (else
           (filter-aux result
                       current-pair
                       (cdr xs)))))
  (let ((init (cons 'throw-me-out '())))
    (filter-aux (cdr init) init list)))
```

Or, using the `let loop` syntax:

```
(define (filter pred? xs)
  (let ((result (cons 'throw-me-out '()))
        (xs xs))
    (let loop ((current-pair result))
      (cond ((null? xs)
             (cdr result))
            ((pred? (car xs))
             (set-cdr! current-pair
                       (cons (car xs) '()))
             (loop (cdr current-pair) (cdr xs)))
            (else
             (loop current-pair (cdr xs)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `filter` as an instance of fold-right:

```
(define (my-filter op xs)
        (fold-right
           (lambda (next result) ...)
           '()
           xs))
```

Hint: use `if` and `cons`

Answer (score 0):

For an alternate tail-recursive `filter` that doesn't require mutable lists, you could use something like this:

```
(define (my-filter f lst)
  (define (iter lst result)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) (reverse result))
      ((f (car lst)) (iter (cdr lst)
                           (cons (car lst) result)))
      (else (iter (cdr lst)
                  result))))
  (iter lst '()))
```

Reverse requires you to walk the list a second time, but it can be implemented in O(n) time with constant stack space on immutable lists, so the overall time is still O(n).